# UIBarButtonItem changes the viewController's orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation, uinavigationbar

I got a `UINavigationBar` with an `.rightBarButtonItem`. If I tap on it, it pushes the new `viewController` and a `.leftBarButtonItem` is brought up automatically which takes me to the `viewController` I was before.

The problem is (when I tap on the `.leftBarButtonItem`) that the orientation is changed from landscape to portrait mode, though I want the app to stay in landscape mode. How can I fix that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you were in portrait mode before you pressed the right button bar item.

It sounds like the first view controller's shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation isn't returning YES for portrait orientations.

Comment: My app starts in Landscape mode, I am in Landscape mode all the time until I press the leftBarButtonItem.

Comment: You were right, can I simply do this?

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); //Before the problem
    return YES;
}

My app supports both Landscape and Portrait mode. I want the view to fit to the device orientation, even if I am in Portrait mode. How can I do this?